# Reduced noise in debug view of stl types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

TL;DR: Can the type information displayed in visual studio debugger/intellisense/compiler output for long type names from stl be cleaned up for the developer?

C++, Visual Studio

Consider the code:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
```

Consider the **type** information in

1. The watch window
   [image: watch window]
2. With a mouse over on the identifier
   [image: mouse over]
3. Intellisense prompt (parameters for a method, image formatted for brevity)
   [image: method parameter]
4. (like #3) intellisense completion for an identifer as you type the name
   [image: intellisense]

Each of these cases is showing type descriptions for stl containers are a long mess of details infrequently needed.

I've noticed visual studio 2011 is now showing `string` as `std::string` (an awesome improvement), instead of `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>` - but this doesn't occur for other stl types I've tested.

I know why it is showing that info, I know the info is correct, and critically important in some cases. It is simply my opinion that most of the time, the developer couldn't care less and `map<int, int>` would be sufficient. Any way to format or configure the output to reduce the noise?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `autoexp.dat` as it controls how to display data and values in the debugger. [How to Write Native C++ Debugger Visualizers in Visual Studio for Complicated Types
Introduction](https://web.archive.org/web/20140405061100/http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83)

Comment: isn't that only for the values and not the type? I'm not talking about values, but the type. I'll add a screenshot. also, that tutorial shows how the Type is never cleaned up

Comment: Besides that being far from a long type-name, it is one of the fundamental issues of C++ errors and debugging. There is nothing you can leave out without hiding essential information.

Comment: @pmr I agree it is essential information - but are you telling me you don't know that (unless some has hacked the names) that `std::map<int, int>` IS `std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int>>>`? Do you have to see that everytime because you forgot or are unsure? This is not essential information you have to see EVERY TIME. That, is my point.

Comment: You certainly have a point. It really depends on the kind of code base. Sometimes I was glad for having that extra bit of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you are looking for STLFilt (http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html).

Courtesy:http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/templates.html#fqa-35.17

Though the cryptic warnings/errors may be cumbersome to decode for a beginner, I would suggest you to get used to it, if you wish to be a pro.

Comment: I can read the cryptic stl output just fine (been writing c++ professionally for many years now), it's just a waste of time to read through it. I'll check your suggestion, thank you.